# C++ map within map initialization

Tags: c++, initializer-list

I have a map defined in the following:

```
map<string, Command> _cmd_map;
```

where `Command` is a class defined as

```
class Command {
public:

    const string description;
    const map<string, Argument> *arguments;
    const CommandFunction function;

    Command(const string &desc, CommandFunction func, map<string, Argument> *args = nullptr);
    Command(const string &desc, CommandFunction func, const map<string, Argument> &args);
};
```

How do I initialize this at the beginning of my .cpp? So far I can do it using initializer_list for Command, with *args = nullptr:

```
const map<string, Command> _cmd_map{
    { "help", Command("Show help menu", (CommandFunction)&(_cmd_help)) },
    { "exit", Command("Exit ", (CommandFunction)&(_cmd_exit)) },
    { "quit", Command("Exit ", (CommandFunction)&(_cmd_exit)) },
}
```

However I cannot initialize the map inside the Command class this way, without creating a map before and passing it as argument.
Is it possible to do this directly, like

```
const map<string, Command> _cmd_map{
{ "quit", Command("Exit ", (CommandFunction)&(_cmd_exit)), 
    {
        {"d1", Argument("Dummy Argument 1")},
        {"d2", Argument("Dummy Argument 2")},
     } 
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you taking the map by lreference rather than const reference, rreference, or value?

Comment: In fact, what is the `Args` map for?  I can't think of how you can use that with the functions in any useful way.

Comment: It is used to validate user inputs before calling the function using those arguments.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that `arguments` is a pointer.  Since it's a pointer to (presumably) an externally managed resource, the resource will (obviously) have to be externally managed.  So: no temporaries.  So: it must have a name.  So: it cannot be done as you wish, unless you are ok with managing the `arguments` object's lifetime.

Comment: But I added another constructor. It should be const lreference, I will correct it. It has the option to be a pointer because this arg list is optional

Comment: Making a const lreference parameter would make it compile, but the map would be destroyed the instant the constructor finished, which defeats the point entirely.  Someone needs to explicitly manage the lifetime of the `map`, period.